# Can ActiveMQ accept messages with Enum headers from Camel?

Tags: enums, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am sending a Camel exchange to activeMQ. Looks essentially like this:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  ENUM_VALUE;
}

// Elsewhere, my route
from( INPUT_URI )
     .setHeader( "someHeader", constant( MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE ))
     .to( "activemq:queue:my.destination" );
```

Everything else is fine. Other String-valued headers I've sent go through fine.

On the receiving side (also Camel), it does not have "someHeader" at all.

Does Camel/ActiveMQ handle enum values in headers, or does it reject them silently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JMS spec. has requirements of which Java types JMS headers (aka JMS properties) is supported.

There is some details at section *Message format when sending* : http://camel.apache.org/jms
and from the JMS spec you can see from the JMS javadoc at: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/jms/Message.html

According to the spec enums is not supported.

Comment: I have adapted our routes accordingly to use anEnum.toString() and MyEnum.valueOf() to transport the enums. Thank you for the response!